# Conditional breakpoints in VScode trip even when condition is false

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Like the title said, any conditional breakpoints I set in VS code are always tripped, even when the condition is false. I right-clicked in the margin, typed the condition into the little box that shows up, and hit enter.  Is the syntax? I tried the following conditions and they were all tripped, even though they're obviously false.

```
(if False)
```

And this:

```
(False)
```

Using Python, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Conditional breakpoints work fine for me, although I am using version `2018.1.0-beta`.

Comment: Conditional breakpoints also work for me in, but I'm also using `2018.1` (which should hopefully be released this week).

Comment: I am using python and also seeing this. If set `1==0` it still breaks.

Answer (score 2):

I fall into a pitfall,

```
foo1 = 1
foo2 = 2
```

If you want to stop when foo1 == 1, you need to set a breakpoint at line 2. At line 1, the foo1 is not defined yet.